# Como mandar uma mensagem dizendo para o usuário a data inicial é maior que a data final?

Tags: java, android

Passei a tarde toda fazendo esse código mas nao conseguir fazer funcionar bem. O que faço para mandar uma mensagem para o usuário dizendo que a hora inicial nao pode ser maior que a hora final?

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.alinesilvagonzaga.myapplication.MainActivity">



<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:id="@+id/textView2" />

<EditText
    android:hint="data inicial"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="246dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="31dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText" />

<EditText
    android:hint="hora inicial"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="time"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:id="@+id/editText2" />

<EditText
    android:hint="data final"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="date"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="173dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText3" />

<EditText
    android:hint="hora final"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="time"
    android:ems="10"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="14dp"
    android:id="@+id/editText5" />

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText5"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:hint="período"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="58dp"
        android:id="@+id/editText4" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

xml DatePicker:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <DatePicker
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/datePicker" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Timerpicker xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TimePicker
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/timePicker" />
</LinearLayout>
```

E a lógica na Activity:

```
    private String segundosInicial = "59";
    private String horainicialRegra = "00:00";
    private String horafinalRegra = "23:59";
    private String segundosFinal = "59";
    private String datafinalregra = "18/12/3000"+" "+horafinalRegra+":"+segundosFinal;
    private String oi;
    private String horaatualok;
    private Date atualhoradata;
    private Date atualhoradatafinal;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        editTextDataInicio = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editTextHoraInicio = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        editTextDataTermino = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        editTextHoraTermino = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText5);
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        editTextHorario = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText4);




        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date dataAtual = calendar.getTime();
        datainicialRegra = dataAtual;
        SimpleDateFormat sdffinal = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        datainicialregra = sdffinal.format(datainicialRegra);
        editTextDataInicio.setText(datainicialregra);

        ano_ = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        mes_ = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        dia_ = String.valueOf(calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        dia_ = "0" + dia_;
        mes_ = "0" + (mes_ + 1);

        try{
            dia_ = dia_.substring(1,3);
        }
        catch (Exception e){

        }

        try{
            mes_ = mes_.substring(1,3);
        }
        catch (Exception e){

        }
        datainicialregra = dia_+"/"+mes_+"/"+ano_;

        try {
            datafinalRegra = sdffinal.parse(datafinalregra);
            datainicialRegra = sdffinal.parse(datainicialregra);

        } catch (ParseException e) {

        }




//
        editTextHoraInicio.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builderTime = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                final View view = ((LayoutInflater) v.getRootView().getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.pegahora, null);
                builderTime.setView(view);
                timePicker = (TimePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

                timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);

                builderTime.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                //coloca aqui
                builderTime.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        datainicialregra = dia_+"/"+mes_+"/"+ano_;
                        Calendar cald = Calendar.getInstance();
                        atualhoradata = cald.getTime();

                        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                        int hora = timePicker.getHour();
                        int minuto = timePicker.getMinute();

                        String tHora = String.valueOf(hora);
                        String mHora = String.valueOf(minuto);
                        int tamHora = tHora.length();
                        int tamMin = mHora.length();
                        //Aqui é para a data inicial ser maior que a data atual.
                        if (tamHora == 1) {
                            horainicialRegra = "0" + hora + ":" + minuto+":"+segundosInicial;
                           // editTextHoraInicio.setText("0" + hora + ":" + minuto);
                        }
                        if (tamMin == 1) {
                            horainicialRegra = hora + ":" + "0" + minuto+":"+segundosInicial;
                            //editTextHoraInicio.setText(hora + ":" + "0" + minuto);
                        }
                        if (tamHora == 1 && tamMin == 1) {
                            horainicialRegra = "0" + hora + ":" + "0" + minuto+":"+segundosInicial;
                            //editTextHoraInicio.setText("0" + hora + ":" + "0" + minuto);
                        }
                        if (tamHora == 2 && tamMin == 2) {
                            horainicialRegra = hora + ":" + minuto+":"+segundosInicial;
                            //editTextHoraInicio.setText(hora + ":" + minuto);
                        }


                        Log.i(":", horainicialRegra);
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                        try {
                            datainicialRegra = sdf.parse(datainicialregra+" "+horainicialRegra);
                            //datafinalRegra = sdf.parse(datafinalregra+" "+horafinalRegra);

                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }

                        Log.i("dataatual", sdf.format(atualhoradata));
                        Log.i("datainicial", sdf.format(datainicialRegra));

                            Log.i("jfhdj", String.valueOf(atualhoradata.compareTo(datainicialRegra)));
                        if(atualhoradata.compareTo(datainicialRegra) > 0){

                            AlertDialog.Builder alertaRegra1 = new  AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
                            alertaRegra1.setMessage("Hora já passou!");
                            alertaRegra1.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                    arg0.dismiss();

                                }
                            });
                            alertaRegra1.create().show();
                        }else {

                            //if (hora >= c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY) && minuto >= c.get(Calendar.MINUTE) || (hora == 0) || ( minuto == 0)) {

                            if (tamHora == 1) {
                               // horainicialRegra = "0" + hora + ":" + minuto;
                                editTextHoraInicio.setText("0" + hora + ":" + minuto);
                            }
                            if (tamMin == 1) {
                               // horainicialRegra = hora + ":" + "0" + minuto;
                                editTextHoraInicio.setText(hora + ":" + "0" + minuto);
                            }
                            if (tamHora == 1 && tamMin == 1) {
                                //horainicialRegra = "0" + hora + ":" + "0" + minuto;
                                editTextHoraInicio.setText("0" + hora + ":" + "0" + minuto);
                            }
                            if (tamHora == 2 && tamMin == 2) {
                               // horainicialRegra = hora + ":" + minuto;
                                editTextHoraInicio.setText(hora + ":" + minuto);
                            }

                        }
                        // }else{
                        //      Toast.makeText(context, "O horário não pode ser anterior ao de agora.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //  }

                    }
                });
                builderTime.create().show();
            }
        });

        editTextHoraTermino.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                final AlertDialog.Builder builderTime2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                final View view = ((LayoutInflater) v.getRootView().getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.pegahora, null);
                builderTime2.setView(view);
                timePicker = (TimePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.timePicker);

                timePicker.setIs24HourView(true);

                builderTime2.setNegativeButton("Cancelar", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                //coloca aqui
                builderTime2.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        //Protótipo:
                        //
                        if(editTextDataTermino.getText().toString().trim().equals("")) {
                            AlertDialog.Builder alertaRegra2 = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
                            alertaRegra2.setMessage("Insira data final do alerta.");
                            alertaRegra2.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                    arg0.dismiss();

                                }
                            });
                            alertaRegra2.create().show();
                        }else {

                            Calendar calendarfinal = Calendar.getInstance();
                            atualhoradatafinal = calendarfinal.getTime();

                            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                            int hora = timePicker.getHour();
                            int minuto = timePicker.getMinute();

                            String tHora = String.valueOf(hora);
                            String mHora = String.valueOf(minuto);
                            int tamHora = tHora.length();
                            int tamMin = mHora.length();

                            if (tamHora == 1) {
                                horafinalRegra = "0" + hora + ":" + minuto + ":" + segundosFinal;
                                // editTextHoraInicio.setText("0" + hora + ":" + minuto);
                            }
                            if (tamMin == 1) {
                                horafinalRegra = hora + ":" + "0" + minuto + ":" + segundosFinal;
                                //editTextHoraInicio.setText(hora + ":" + "0" + minuto);
                            }
                            if (tamHora == 1 && tamMin == 1) {
                                horafinalRegra = "0" + hora + ":" + "0" + minuto + ":" + segundosFinal;
                                //editTextHoraInicio.setText("0" + hora + ":" + "0" + minuto);
                            }
                            if (tamHora == 2 && tamMin == 2) {
                                horafinalRegra = hora + ":" + minuto + ":" + segundosFinal;
                                //editTextHoraInicio.setText(hora + ":" + minuto);
                            }


                            Log.i(":", horainicialRegra);
                            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
                            try {
                                datafinalRegra = sdf.parse(datafinalregra+" "+horafinalRegra);
                                //datafinalRegra = sdf.parse(datafinalregra+" "+horafinalRegra);

                            } catch (Exception e) {

                            }

                            Log.i("dataatual", sdf.format(atualhoradatafinal));
                            Log.i("datainicial", sdf.format(datafinalRegra));

                            Log.i("jfhdj", String.valueOf(atualhoradatafinal.compareTo(datafinalRegra)));
                            if (atualhoradatafinal.compareTo(datafinalRegra) > 0) {

                                AlertDialog.Builder alertaRegra1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
                                alertaRegra1.setMessage("Hora já passou!");
                                alertaRegra1.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                                        arg0.dismiss();

                                    }
                                });
                                alertaRegra1.create().show();
                            } else {

                                if (tamHora == 1) {
                                    // horainicialRegra = "0" + hora + ":" + minuto;
                                    editTextHoraTermino.setText("0" + hora + ":" + minuto);
                                }
                                if (tamMin == 1) {
                                    // horainicialRegra = hora + ":" + "0" + minuto;
                                    editTextHoraTermino.setText(hora + ":" + "0" + minuto);
                                }
                                if (tamHora == 1 && tamMin == 1) {
                                    //horainicialRegra = "0" + hora + ":" + "0" + minuto;
                                    editTextHoraTermino.setText("0" + hora + ":" + "0" + minuto);
                                }
                                if (tamHora == 2 && tamMin == 2) {
                                    // horainicialRegra = hora + ":" + minuto;
                                    editTextHoraTermino.setText(hora + ":" + minuto);
                                }

                            }
                        }
```

Comment: Está acontecendo algum erro?

Comment: Não....Tem erro de lógica mesmo...o timepicker está funcionando bem...não sei onde está o erro de lógica :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No seu código em nenhum momento você está comparando as horas que o usuário colocou, mas sim comparando cada uma com a hora atual. Pelo que você descreveu na pergunta, não é isso que você quer fazer (e o seu código ta bem confuso, demorei bastante pra conseguir ver certinho o que tava acontecendo, tem varias variáveis que são instanciadas mas não são usadas (Calendar c por exemplo)

Você precisa salvar os valores das horas selecionadas pelo usuário em uma member variable (acessível pra toda a classe) e fazer essa validação, ou na hora que o usuário apertar algum botão de confirmação, ou usando alguma flag pra controlar se as duas horas foram preenchidas, e então realizar a comparação.

Outra coisa, você está comparando as Strings já formatadas no seu compareTo, porque não comparar os objetos Date? Faz mais sentido.

Eu te recomendo dar uma olhada no [JodaTime](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/), uma biblioteca MUITO usada pra manipular datas/horas em Java.

Tenta dar uma olhada nessa [resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19109999/3473971) do SO gringo, ele compara os objetos Date.

Comment: Poderia me dar um conselho ou escrever um código de como vc faria, para mim? se não quiser nao tem problema....

Comment: sou novata.........

Comment: @Aline editei a resposta com mais alguns detalhes, no momento nao posso escrever codigo mas com isso ja deve clarificar.

Comment: jodaTime hora de usar